# visual relation Identifier in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

i am using visual relation Identifier in QTP for setting a value in webedit.Here is my code

```
Set rc = VisualRelations.Create
Set relation = rc.Add 
relation.relatedobjectpath = "Browser(""ABC"").Page(""XYZ"").WebElement(""innertext:=E-Mail ID"")"
relation.relativeposition = micRelLeft
relation.setargument micrelinline, True
Set des=Description.Create
des.Add "micclass","WebEdit"
des.Add "visual relations",rc
Browser("ABC").Page("XYZ").WebEdit(des).set "qtpuser@abc.com"
Set relation = Nothing
Set rc = Nothing
```

The problem is when i use description programming for webElement in Line 3 the QTP showing an error message "Cannot find "webedit" objects parent". But, when i store webelement "E-Mail id" in OR, the code is working fine without any error.

Can u please tell me what can i do in this case to resolve the issue.
Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a limitation in QTP that the anchor test object in VRI must be in the object repository.

Thankfully there is a workaround, you can create a dummy anchor test object in the OR with a description of a blank **innertext** (by using the *Define New Test Object* button).

[image: Screen shot of object repository]

Then use `SetTOProperty` to get the dynamic behaviour you can achieve with descriptive programming.

```
Set rc = VisualRelations.Create
Set relation = rc.Add 
Browser("ABC").Page("XYZ").WebElement("Anchor").SetTOProperty "innertext", "E-Mail ID"
relation.relatedobjectpath = "Browser(""ABC"").Page(""XYZ"").WebElement(""Anchor"")"
relation.relativeposition = micRelLeft
relation.setargument micrelinline, True
Set des=Description.Create
des.Add "micclass","WebEdit"
des.Add "visual relations",rc
Browser("ABC").Page("XYZ").WebEdit(des).set "qtpuser@abc.com"
Set relation = Nothing
Set rc = Nothing
```

Comment: Remove "Browser(""ABC"").Page(""XYZ"").WebElement(""innertext:=E-Mail ID"")" in line 2 and run the code. Its working for me..thank u #Motti

Comment: Oops, my bad, please verify the answer is correct now for future generations :)

Comment: @TheBlastOne, you're right, I don't know how that got there... Thanks!

Comment: Now I am wondering how I would specify "related object is closest on X (`micRelClosestX`) *AND* to the left" (`micRelLeft`)". I can do that in the QTP GUI, but not in the API, because I would need to assign two values to `.RelativePosition`. Right? Or -- how would you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps add two separate relations? Yuck I know.
Actually that's what the example in the documentation does.

Comment: Well, I got it: you can state only one of both in .RelativePositon. You are right, you have to add two relations. 

And the QTP GUI creates two relation entries if you check both "left" and "closest on the x-axis", indeed. Fascinating :-\

Answer (score 0):

When you store the WebElement "E-Mail id" in OR, its parent Page(""XYZ"") will also be stored into OR.
The problem is that OR way is used to identify Page, but the DP way is used to identify the WebElement. If you delete the WebElement "E-Mail id" but remain the Page("XYZ"), the script should work well.